# What is the most reliable math phd ranking?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, mathematics, ranking

There are a lot of subjects rankings of world universities availible: usworld, qs, shanghai. They all agree on the first 10 positions but differ dramatically even on the top 50. Moreover, I am sure they take some data into account which may be irrelevant for grad school, like quality of undergrad courses. What is the best way to estimate the prestige of a grad school?

For example, take The Hebrew University of Jerusalem. It is considered top 25 in Shanghai ranking, but is not in the top 100 for usworld and qs.

Lets assume "prestige" to be the ratio of good postdoc positions obtained by graduates.

Comment: A good way is to ask a researcher in the area you are interested in.

Comment: Why is this important?

Comment: How do you define “good postdoc positions”? I think your definition is self-referential. By the way, this self-referential property is actually a standard phenomenon with ranking questions. One answer to this is offered by the [PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) algorithm, but I don’t think anyone has implemented a version of it in the context of grad school rankings. (In other words, your question, while interesting, is basically an open problem.)

Comment: If you care about job placement of graduates, then you're probably better off researching this directly than using any of the rankings that you've mentioned.  One way to do this is to look at some fairly recent PhD graduates (you probably want to see how grads are doing 3-5 years after completing the PhD)  and see where they are employed.

Comment: *"Lets assume "prestige" to be the ratio of good postdoc positions obtained by graduates."* Why am I under the impression that this is quite a stretch of the word "prestige"...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Lets assume "prestige" to be the ratio of good postdoc positions obtained by graduates

This is exactly why rankings differ dramatically. "Prestige" is extremely subjective, and the ranking depends on what you assumptions you make.

If you want to know where a PhD program's graduates ended up, you might be able to find that with some internet sleuthing. It would be tedious to come up with an entire ranking this way, but you could certainly compare a few programs which you're interested in.

Which is what you should do anyway. Rankings are rough guides, but they are no substitute for you thinking long and hard about what is important to you, and then researching which programs best meet your needs.